# list access rights in path

Tags: linux, shell, ls

Is there a better way (avoid repeated replacements) to list access rights in path

```
echo "/asdf/asd/asdas/asdasd/asdasd/asdwer" | sed -Ee 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' \
-e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' -e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' \
-e 's#((.*)/.*)#\1\n\2#' | sort -u | xargs ls -dl
```

Comment: Does your system provide the `namei` command? if so, you can try `namei -l /asdf/asd/asdas/asdasd/asdasd/asdwer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little shell loop would do it:

```
p=/var/log/messages
while [ $p != "/" ]; do ls -ld "$p"; p=$(dirname "$p"); done; ls -ld "$p"
```

Sample output:

```
-rw-------.  1 root root 241859 Apr 10 09:23 /var/log/messages
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root   4096 Apr 10 03:32 /var/log
drwxr-xr-x. 26 root root   4096 Dec 13 16:10 /var
dr-xr-xr-x. 30 root root   4096 Dec 13 16:10 /
```